# How do you customize kendoUI Grid Column Menu for Mobile

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-mobile

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/ac2xs8uz/35/)

[Column Menu INIT Example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnMenuInit)

```
columnMenuInit: function (e) {
                console.log("menu init");
                var field = e.field;
                console.log(field);

                    var menu = e.container.find(".k-menu").data("kendoMenu");
                    menu.append([
                    {text: "Highlight",
                        spriteCssClass: "k-i-custom",
                        content: '<div class="colorpicker' + field + '"></div>'
                    }]);
                    $(".colorpicker" + field).kendoFlatColorPicker({
                        preview: false,
                        value: "#000",
                        change: select
                    });
};
```

The following code above shows how to add a menu item for the desktop view.  But the moment you want to add a menu item for adaptive rendering mode of the grid, the menu item does not appear? I wanted to add a custom menu for highlighting.

After some research I believe that in adaptive rendering mode it uses a [mobile list view](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/listview#methods-append) instead of the kendoui menu.  I'm not sure how to access this list however.

I've tried some code like below with no luck, says menu not found.

```
var menu = e.container.find(".k-mobile-list").data("kendoMenu");
                    if(menu){
                        console.log("found");
                    }else{
                        console.log("not found");
                    }
```

I have also tried,

```
var menu = e.container.find(".k-mobile-list").data("kendoMobileListView");
                    if(menu){
                        console.log("found");
                    }else{
                        console.log("not found");
                    }
```

no luck here either.

The container on mobile which I extracted from iOS simulator from a `console.log(e.container);`command looks like below.

```
<div class="k-column-menu k-mobile-list"><ul data-role=""><li><span class="k-link">Company Name</span><ul><li class="k-item k-sort-asc"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-i-sort-asc"></span>Sort Ascending</span></li><li class="k-item k-sort-desc"><span class="k-link"><span class="k-sprite k-i-sort-desc"></span>Sort Descending</span></li><li class="k-item k-filter-item"><span class="k-link k-filterable" data-role="filtermenu"><span class="k-sprite k-filter"></span>Filter</span></li></ul></li><li class="k-columns-item"><span class="k-link">Columns</span><ul><li class="k-item"><label class="k-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-check" data-field="name" data-index="0" data-locked="false">Company Name</label></li><li class="k-item"><label class="k-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-check" data-field="phone" data-index="1" data-locked="false">Phone</label></li><li class="k-item"><label class="k-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-check" data-field="email" data-index="2" data-locked="false">Email</label></li><li class="k-item"><label class="k-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-check" data-field="Operations" data-index="3" data-locked="false">Operations</label></li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Does anyone know how to add to the menu items with adaptive rendering enabled for the grid?

Comment: anyone got any ideas?